# How can I prove $7n+8$ is odd iff $n$ is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $n$ be an integer. prove that $n$ is odd iff $7n+8$ is odd.
my solution is:

1) since $n$ is an integer.
                2) so I let $n=2k+1$
                3) I substitute $n$ in $7n+8$
                4) I get $14k+15$

but I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: $7n$ is odd when $n$ is odd. $8$ is even, Odd+even is what??

Comment: $$7n+8\equiv n\pmod2$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to consider:

1. If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k.$ Substitute $2k+1$ for $n$ in $7n+8,$ then try to rewrite the resulting expression in the form $2m+1$ for some integer $m.$
2. If $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ for some integer $k.$ Substitute $2k$ for $n$ in $7n+8,$ then try to rewrite the resulting expression in the form $2m$ for some integer $m.$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd, then $7n$ is also odd.  What happens when you add an odd number and an even number?

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is odd iff $7n+8$ is odd

($\Rightarrow$) If $n$ is odd, $n = 2k+1$. So, $7n+8 = 14k+7+8 = 14k + 14 + 1 = 2(7k+7) + 1$. Thus, $7n+8$ is odd.

($\Leftarrow$) If $7n+8$ is odd, then $7n+8 = 1$ (mod 2). But $7=1$ (mod 2) and $8=0$ (mod2). Replacing, $n=1$ (mod2). Thus, $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since you are trying to show something is odd, reduce everything mod 2. If your answer comes out to be congruent to 1 mod 2, then you have shown it is odd. The converse follows in a similar fashion.